# Does anyone knows how DB2 Recovery Expert works, when extracting transaction logs?

Tags: logging, transactions, db2, extract

I am writing a sql2nosql synchronizing tool by java. I gotta to extract DB2 history archived transaction logs, however not like Oracle logmnr, DB2 has no suitable API or method, except her own tool 'Recovery Expert'.Don't mention snapshot or event monitor for me, because I am analyzing history archived logs.

Does anyone help me how DB2 Recovery Expert works, when extracting logs?

Regards Deyin from China

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 has had the [`db2ReadLog()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001673.html) API for a *long* time.